# Array to string with Django and MySQL

Tags: html, sql, arrays, django, list

I need to design SQL query in html on Django

I have an array in my table like :

```
list = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

When I call this array in my page :

```
<p>{{ list }}</p>
```

I have : ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']

What do I do if I want :

a

b

c

I tried with *.split(',')* but I've already '[]'

I tried with *for item in list* but I've :

[

a

a

,

b

b

,

c

c

,

]

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to load it as a json but it doesn't work.

I've solved my problem with

```
import ast
lst = ast.literal_eval(st)
```

Answer (score 0):

load it as a json, using

```
import json
lst = json.loads(st)
```